# Convert datetime to ISO format (e.g. with moment.js) in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can you please advise the simplest method to convert date time e.g. "14/03/2016 2:25:15 PM" to ISO format "2016-03-14T14:25:15" in javascript

Thanks

Comment: [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/)

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = moment();
date.toISOString();
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/